# Return Value From One Workbook' VBA To Another Workbook' VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have two workbooks with VBAs. I would like to pass the value returned from wbA!VBA1 to wbB!VBA2; both workbooks would be running under the same Excel application.

For example, in wbA!VBA1, there is

`x = function()`, which would return integer 0 if run successfully;

I want to pass the returned value `0` to wbB!VBA2 for other operations.

Comment: How are you calling the functions? Can you post the code?

Comment: @Comintern `x = function()`

Comment: I saw that already - can you post the code that surrounds `x = function()`? It's not clear from the question whether this is inside a VBA function, a cell formula, called via Interop, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see that you are asking. You want to be able to store a variable from WbA inside of VBA and the view it in VBA in WbB. To my knowledge that would not be possible as it the variables are created at run time. Once the process has finished then it all variables get cleared. One thing to look into would be to run the VBA in wbA and store what ever variables you need in a very hidden sheet. That way in wbB you can call the VBA for that and then get the variables you have stored in the very hidden sheet.

So you would be getting the variables but they will not be at run time. You would have to call each macro seperatly.

Or another way would be to have the code stored in a personal macro book or another workbook, you would then need to set references to wbA and wbB. Then the code will be ran in seperatly and then you can view the variables in VBA.